# *Highcharts* Zoom Option and Update values in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart like this example http://jsfiddle.net/2mvuLLs9/5/. In the legend it displays the total amount which I used for loop to count manually:

```
for(var j =0; j< value.length;j++){
   total[j]=0;
   for(var k =0; k<value[j][1].length;k++){
      total[j]= total[j]+value[j][1][k][1];
   }    
}
```

. 
I use also the zoom option:
`zoomType : 'x'`
to focus on the area that interested. Question here is : is it possible to update again the legend that shows the total amount only of the area that I zoomed ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Could probably use the `selection` event to count the values in range and update legend labels.

Comment: @Halvor: sorry I didnt get that could you please tell a litte bit in details ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by updating your series parameters. You can update it inside callback function for afterSetExtremes event:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes

Inside it you can use getExtremes() to get new min and max value of your axis.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes

You can just check if your series point is between min and max value and sum values of all points that are between. Then you can change your customlegendText.

```
            afterSetExtremes: function () {
                var sum = 0;
                min = parseFloat(this.getExtremes().min);
                max = parseFloat(this.getExtremes().max);
                Highcharts.each(this.series, function (p, i) {
                    sum = 0;
                    Highcharts.each(p.data, function (ob, j) {
                        if (min <= ob.x && ob.x <= max) {
                            sum += ob.y;
                        }
                    });
                    p.userOptions.customlegendText = sum;
                });
                this.series[0].update({});
            }
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/2mvuLLs9/11/